# How to change specific html tag attribute inside a multiple other tag using css

Tags: html, css, font-size

I'm trying to change the font color of my html "p" tag located deep inside a html "div" tag. This is my html code:

```
<div class="footcolor">
<table>
    <td width="300">
           <div style="text-align:justify; margin-left: 10px">
           <h5 style="color:#FF0; font-weight:bold">INFORMATION</h5>
           <p>ABOUT US</p>
           <p>PRIVACY POLICY</p>
           <p>TERMS & CONDITION</p>
           <p>OUR PARTNER</p>
           </div>
    </td>
</table>
</div>
```

And this is what I have tried using CSS based on what I understand from the web

```
.footcolor p {
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:9px;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to change? what is tag?

Comment: You can't change attribute with css. What you want to do ?

Comment: So what is wrong? Your css should work. Unless there is some other `p` parent with color set

Comment: @Coder what I mean by tag is html p tag and div tag, I'm trying to edit the font color and font size of the "p" that is located inside the "div"

Comment: @Justinas thank you. you were right there is another css code that is influencing the attribute of my 'p' tag. Thank you for everyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="footcolor">
<table>
    <td width="300">
           <div class="innerDiv">
             <h5 style="color:#FF0; font-weight:bold">INFORMATION</h5>
             <p>ABOUT US</p>
             <p>PRIVACY POLICY</p>
             <p>TERMS & CONDITION</p>
             <p>OUR PARTNER</p>
           </div>
    </td>
</table>
</div>
```

and

```
.innerdiv {
  text-align:justify; 
   margin-left: 10px;
}
.innerdiv p {
  // do whatever you would like
}
```